# How to map to Array Data Type in h2

Tags: java, sql, arrays, h2

I'm setting up a h2 database. Therefore i created a java class and wanted to map the attributes to Data Types in h2, but it doesn't work for the Array Data Type. What mapping do I have to use?

I'm pretty new to programming and this might be an easy to solve question.

```
@Entity
public class dummy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String cola;
    private Long[] colb;
}
```

No matter what java.lang I use, the Data Type of colb is always BINARY in h2. The other ones are fine.

Let me know if you need some more information. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never used this, but just read some of the docs.  Seems like it might be literally `Object[]`? [Here](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html) is my source.

Comment: @Nexevis. Sorry, should have mentioned that I already tried Object[]. I now that source and tried the different mappings.